# is it possible to have pivot operation spring-data-mongodb?

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data

I am new to mongodb and spring data, is it possible to have pivot operation as mentioned pivot in mongodb. I am repeating this question in spring forums, because I am not getting pivot from spring web site example. I have data of this form:

```
  Name| SumPrice| type|year 
     A|    50.0|     Retail|2015
     B|    467.0|    Online|2015
     A|    1456.0|   Direct|2015
     B|    1149.53|  Direct|2015
     C|     273.20|  Online|2014
     C|     110.0|   Direct|2014
```

For this I created a java class :

```
   class SampleReport{

 private String name;
 private Double sumUnitPrice;
 private String type;
 private Integer year;
  }
```

I want to pivot w.r.t. type field and want the data of the form :

```
  Name |Retail| Online | Direct| year
      A|     50.0 |  0.0|    1456.0 |    2015
      B|     0.0|    467.0|  1149.53|  2015
      C|     0.0|    273.20| 110.0|     2014
```

Please lemme know how to do the same with spring-data

Regards

Kris